# Use python to automate interaction?

Tags: python, linux, automation

Is it possible to use python in order to automate interaction in Linux? (for example, sending "Yes" to StdInput whenever the string "Are you sure?" is sent to StdOutput)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/).